# error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c

I'm trying to do some calculation program using C what am I getting error is

`error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment`

This error cause from define a value on the header and then I assign using `=` in the main body.

If I put that value which it is in the header instead put them in the `int` or `double` then it will be fine, but I don't want them to be there.

please tell me if needed more information about what I'm trying to say.

Thanks

---

here is what I put on the define `#define price 50`

and in the body where I'm getting error `price = price * 2 + total`

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: @Mat I don't know if this is enough

Comment: Ali, yes, it's enough :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign to a define! After the preprocessor is done, to the compiler the code looks like this:

```
50 = 50 * 2 + total;
```

Comment: Yes I understand that the line will equal to something like `price = 50 * 2 + 300 [assume total = 300]` but I don't know why my professor asking me to instead using `#define` not the `int` or `double`

Comment: yes but when I remove the value from `int` and use them in `#define` then I'm getting this error and my professor seem not to give me any information how will this work since from my understanding and from where I did the research and also from here getting the same result that it can't be done this way.

Comment: @Ali Perhaps you're supposed to store the value in a different variable ? Something like `final_price = price * 2 + total;` ?

Comment: Thanks for giving me an idea I will try that

Comment: the only problem now is that if I use something like this `final_price = price / total` the output is always 0 so I tried show the output for the `price` itself by using `printf("%d", price); and it shows the value correctly. I don't know what is wrong exactly

Comment: Take a look at the difference between division using ints and division using floats. In division using ints, 3/4 always equals 0. Your printf() format specifier says that you are using ints. Maybe you should use floats and the %f format specifier?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that price is being replaced with the text 50. You can't have

```
50 = ...
```

in C. Can't do it.